k9s only shows around 50-100 lines of logs, despite more logs being available
I've started using k9s, a TUI for exploring a kubernetes cluster.
When I use it to view logs, it however only shows me around 50-100 lines, instead of all the logs, or at least a decent chunk of them. This makes the log viewer quite useless.
How do I fix this?
A partial fix is to change the config k9s.logger.tail to a value higher than 100.
One can find the location of the config file through k9s info:
$ k9s info
 ____  __.________
|    |/ _/   __   \______
|      < \____    /  ___/
|    |  \   /    /\___ \
|____|__ \ /____//____  >
        \/            \/

Version:           0.32.5
Config:            /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/config.yaml
Custom Views:      /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/views.yaml
Plugins:           /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/plugins.yaml
Hotkeys:           /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/hotkeys.yaml
Aliases:           /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/aliases.yaml
Skins:             /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/skins
Context Configs:   /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/clusters
Logs:              /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/k9s.log
Benchmarks:        /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/benchmarks
ScreenDumps:       /Users/corneliusromer/Library/Application Support/k9s/screen-dumps

Then editing the line:
k9s:
  ...
  logger:
    tail: 5000 <--- increase from 100 to say 5000
    buffer: 5000
    sinceSeconds: -1
    textWrap: false
    showTime: false

This will work sometimes, but not reliable in my experience. A proper, real fix would be welcome.
